# Library is not recognized when the apk is generated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library in the libs folder, and I refer the library in my gradle file:

```
provided files('libs/com.symbol.emdk.jar')
```

When I generate the apk, the app starts but throws an Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.symbol.emdk.barcode.Scanner com.symbol.emdk.barcode.BarcodeManager.getDevice(com.symbol.emdk.barcode.BarcodeManager$DeviceIdentifier)' on a null object reference

If I add the library from locally path, and generate the apk and this works correctly,

```
provided fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: '/Users/mocasti/Desktop/EMDK-A-0607095-MAC/SDK/addon-symbol_emdk-symbol-23/libs')
```

I need to add the library in the project but I don't understand why the app throws the error.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable, EMDKManager.EMDKListener, Scanner.DataListener, Scanner.StatusListener, View.OnTouchListener {

/**
 * Extra name that holds the request to start the scanner
 */
public static final String START_SCANNER_EXTRA = "startScanner";

/**
 * The empty string
 */
public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

/**
 * Last scanned ScanDataCollection.  We keep this object to ensure that we discard data when the Scanner scans more than once the same item on a single try.
 */
private ScanDataCollection lastScanned;

/**
 * Declare the button for open the scanner upc.
 */
private Button verifierDetailsButton;

/**
 * Declare a variable to store ProfileManager object
 */
private ProfileManager mainProfileManager;

/**
 * Declare a variable to store EMDKManager object
 */
private EMDKManager emdkManager;

/**
 * Allows  process  Runnable objects associated with a thread's.
 */
private Handler handler;

/**
 * This is the scanner.
 */
private Scanner scanner;

/**
 * This is the primary object to access the barcode scanning feature.
 */
private BarcodeManager barcodeManager;
/**
 * This is a flag for the IP/Device ID button
 */
private  boolean isTouched=true;
/**
 * This is a starting time for the IP/Device ID button.
 */
private long timeInActionDown=0L;

private Runnable mainTimerExecutor = this;



/**
 * It's the first method called when the activity is created.
 * The EMDKManager object will be created and returned in the callback.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    verifierDetailsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verifierDetailsButton);
    verifierDetailsButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

    StoreFormatCustom storeFormatCustom = StoreFormatCustom.getInstance();
    VideoActivity.setVideoName(storeFormatCustom.getVideoName());

    showMainFragment();
    EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getApplicationContext(), this);
}

/**
 * Validate if the action is already finished or an item was scanned.
 *
 * @param intent
 */
public void validateScanAction(Intent intent){
    if(intent!=null){

        //Check if the intent corresponds to the back action.
        //If the  intent.getExtras() is not null, it's because the scanning action is over.
        //We don't need to do anything if the action is null, because the action already finished.
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null){
            String upcParameter=intent.getExtras().getString(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_KEY);
            if(upcParameter!=null){
                onNewIntent(intent);
            }
        }
        //Checks if you have the right broadcast intent, the action corresponds to EMDK.
        //If the intent.getAction() is not null, we can get the upc scanned. We don't need to do
        //anything if the action is null.
        if(intent.getAction()!=null){
            boolean contentAction =intent.getAction().contentEquals(PriceVerifierConstants.EMDK_SAMPLE_RECVR);
            if(contentAction){
                onNewIntent(intent);
            }

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Calls the Scanner Upc activity for put the upc of the item scanned.
 */
public void openScanner() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScannerUpcActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


/**
 * Configure the emdk with a specific profile.
 *  Get the ProfileManager object to process the profiles
 * Call processPrfoile with profile name and SET flag to create the
 * profile.
 *
 * The scan validation needs to execute from the onOpened method because
 * when the videoActivity start the first time the scanner does not turn off
 * the light.
 *
 * @param emdkManager
 */
@Override
public void onOpened(EMDKManager emdkManager) {
    this.emdkManager = emdkManager;

    mainProfileManager = (ProfileManager)emdkManager.getInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.PROFILE);

    if(mainProfileManager != null) {
        mainProfileManager
                .processProfile(PriceVerifierConstants.PROFILE_NAME, ProfileManager.PROFILE_FLAG.SET, new String[1]);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_IS_EMPTY_EXTRA, true);
    validateScanAction(intent);
}


/**
 * The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.
 * Clean up the objects created by EMDK manager.
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mainTimerExecutor);
    super.onDestroy();

    mainProfileManager=null;

    if(emdkManager!=null){
        emdkManager.release();
        emdkManager=null;
    }

}


/**
 *  This function is responsible for getting the data from the intent.
 *  Disable the scanner when the upc scanned was received.
 *  @param intentData
 */
private void handleDecodeData(Intent intentData) {
    disableScanner();

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, PriceVerifierActivity.class);

    if(intentData.getExtras() != null) {
        String upcScanned = intentData.getStringExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_TEXT_VIEW_VALUE);

        if(upcScanned != null) {

            sendIntent.putExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_TEXT_VIEW_VALUE, upcScanned);
        }
    }

    if(intentData.getAction() != null && intentData.getAction().contentEquals(PriceVerifierConstants.EMDK_INTENT_ACTION)) {
            // Get the source of the data
            String source = intentData.getStringExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.EMDK_SOURCE_DATA);

            // Check if the data has come from the Barcode scanner
            if(source.equalsIgnoreCase(PriceVerifierConstants.DATA_SCANNER)) {
                // Get the data from the intent
                String data = intentData.getStringExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.EMDK_INTENT_DATA);

                // Check that we have received data
                if(data != null && data.length() > 0) {

                    sendIntent.putExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_TEXT_VIEW_VALUE, data);
                }

            }
    }
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}

private boolean isAppBeingRestored(Intent intent){
    Set<String> categories = intent.getCategories();
    boolean hasCategories = categories != null;

    return hasCategories && categories.contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
}

private void conditionalHandle(Intent intent){
    if(!isAppBeingRestored(intent)){
        handleDecodeData(intent);
    }
}



/**
 * Set the upc respect the action (start | finish).
 *
 * We need to handle any incoming intents, so let override the onNewIntent
 * method.
 *
 *
 * @param intent
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle dataIntent = intent.getExtras();
    String upc = EMPTY_STRING;
    boolean turnScannerOn = false;

    if(dataIntent != null) {
        turnScannerOn = dataIntent.getBoolean(START_SCANNER_EXTRA);
        String upcScanned=dataIntent.getString(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_KEY);
        if( upcScanned!= null
                && !upcScanned.isEmpty()) {
            upc = upcScanned;
        }
    }

    // As this method is being triggered every time a new Intent occurs, we have to detour
    // to enabling the scanner or to read the UPC.
    if(turnScannerOn){
        enableScanner();
    }else if (upc.equals(EMPTY_STRING)
            && !dataIntent.getBoolean(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_IS_EMPTY_EXTRA)) {
        conditionalHandle(intent);
    }
}






/**
 * This method isn't used for the moment,
 * The method is implemented from the EMDKManager interface.
 */
@Override
public void onClosed() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



/**
 * Remove the call backs in the timer.
 */
@Override
public void onStop() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mainTimerExecutor);
    super.onStop();
}

/**
 * Thread that count the seconds before change the screen.
 */
@Override
public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(START_SCANNER_EXTRA, true);
        startActivity(intent);

}

/**
 * Return to the video when you are in the main activity screen.
 */
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    handler = new Handler();

    StoreFormatCustom storeFormatCustom = StoreFormatCustom.getInstance();

    if(areThereVideos(storeFormatCustom.getVideoName())){

        handler.postDelayed(mainTimerExecutor, PriceVerifierConstants.MAX_DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
}


/**
 * Disable the scanner (DataWedge and EMDK).
 */
public void disableScanner(){
        barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager)emdkManager.getInstance(FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
        scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);

        try {
            scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.HARD;
            scanner.disable();
            }
        catch(ScannerException e) {
            EmailContentBuilder emailContentBuilder= new EmailContentBuilder();
            ErrorEmailBean errorMailBean= emailContentBuilder.buildEmailContent(e);
            SendNotificationTask sendNotificationTask= new SendNotificationTask();
            sendNotificationTask.execute(errorMailBean);
    }
}

/**
 * This method enables the scanner (EMDK only).
 */
public void enableScanner(){

    barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager)emdkManager.getInstance(FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
    scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);

    try {

        if (scanner.isReadPending()){
            scanner.cancelRead();
        }

        scanner.enable();
        scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.SOFT_ONCE;
        scanner.addDataListener(this);
        scanner.addStatusListener(this);

        scanner.read();

    }
    catch(ScannerException e) {
        EmailContentBuilder emailContentBuilder= new EmailContentBuilder();
        ErrorEmailBean errorMailBean= emailContentBuilder.buildEmailContent(e);
        SendNotificationTask sendNotificationTask= new SendNotificationTask();
        sendNotificationTask.execute(errorMailBean);
    }
}


/**
 * Retrieve the upc scanned and it is send to the MainActivity.
 * @param scanDataCollection
 */
@Override
public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {
    if(!scanDataCollection.equals(lastScanned)){
        lastScanned = scanDataCollection;
        String data=scanDataCollection.getScanData().get(0).getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PriceVerifierConstants.UPC_TEXT_VIEW_VALUE, data.toString());
        conditionalHandle(intent);

    }


}

/**
 * In this method it is not necessary to do anything, but it is necessary to implement it
 * from the StatusLister interface, when the scanner is enabled we need to add
 * the DataListener and the StatusListener.
 *
 * @param statusData
 */
@Override
public void onStatus(StatusData statusData) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

The error is thrown in this line:

```
scanner = barcodeManager.getDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Use `compile files('libs/com.symbol.emdk.jar')` instead of provided

Comment: I already try with compile, release implementation, implementation, but the result is the same :(

Comment: It should work with `implementation`. May be the issue not in gradle. Could you add the code then?

Comment: From the documentation `emdkManager.getInstance()`: "Calling this method before EMDKManager opened will return null." Could it be your case?

Comment: The other thing is, If I run the app with debug mode with the library included in libs folder this works fine, the only problem is when I generated the apk

Comment: The OnOpened method is executed before, then the emdkManager.getInstance() is executed.